# Cannot convert value of type string to type url in coercion

Tags: ios, swift, string, url

> I'm receiving the error Cannot convert value of type string
>   to type url in coercion at this constant. Thanks for the help ahead of time :)
>
> ```
> **let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: JobUrl as URL)**
> ```

```
import UIKit
import SafariServices


class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    //Indeed API Query as JSON
   final let urlString = "http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=9727336427429597&as_phr=&as_any=&as_not=&as_ttl=&as_cmp=&jt=parttime&st=&salary=&radius=25&l=32304&fromage=any&limit=25&sort=&psf=advsrch=&userip=1.2.3.4&useragent=Mozilla/%2F4.0%28Firefox%29&v=2&format=json"


    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var jobTitleArray = [String]()
    var snippetArray = [String]()
    var companyArray = [String]()
    var cityArray = [String]()
    var jobUrlArray = [String]()

//    url = URL(string: epsDictionary["link"] as! String)





    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.downloadJsonWithURL()


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        //dispose of any resources that can be recreated
    }

    //fetch Json
    func downloadJsonWithURL() {
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as? URL)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) ->
            Void in

            if let JsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments)
                as? NSDictionary {
                print(JsonObj!.value(forKey: "results")!)

                if let resultsArray = JsonObj!.value(forKey: "results") as? NSArray {
                    for result in resultsArray {
                        if let resultDict = result as? NSDictionary {

                            if let jobTitle = resultDict.value(forKey: "jobtitle") {
                                self.jobTitleArray.append(jobTitle as! String)
                            }
                            if let snippet = resultDict.value(forKey: "snippet") {
                                self.snippetArray.append(snippet as! String)
                            }
                            if let company = resultDict.value(forKey: "company") {
                                self.companyArray.append(company as! String)
                            }
                            if let city = resultDict.value(forKey: "formattedRelativeTime") {
                                self.cityArray.append(city as! String)
                            }
                            if let jobUrl1 = resultDict.value(forKey: "url") {
                                self.jobUrlArray.append(jobUrl1 as! String)
                            }


                            OperationQueue.main.addOperation({ 
                                self.tableView.reloadData()
                            })
                        }

                    }
                }

            }

        }).resume()
    }


    func downloadJsonWithTask() {
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)

        var downloadTask = URLRequest(url: (url as? URL)!, cachePolicy: URLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData, timeoutInterval: 20)

        downloadTask.httpMethod = "Get"


        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as? URL)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) ->
        Void in

        let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments)

            print(jsonData!)

        }).resume()

    }


     var jobToUrl = URL(string: "http://www.indeed.com/viewjob?jk=5de353a4c580dce0&qd=8FiWEXDXvmdNb_GJC9BAOpLFMiNO7rztIOPtGp_-cISTa1VWcmBigetsBoobMSCXdNyr-z6ge7UiYg2Mx15EH6m1Aj3izkOw87NHJgxznYA&indpubnum=9727336427429597&atk=1bchrhjof5hgga1k")



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)


        print("USER SELECTED CELL")
        let JobUrl = jobUrlArray[indexPath.row]


        **let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: JobUrl as URL)**
        self.present(safariVC, animated: true, completion: nil)



    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return jobTitleArray.count
    }


     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableViewCell
        cell.jobTitle.text = jobTitleArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.jobSummary.text = snippetArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.employerName.text = companyArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.cityName.text = cityArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.ApplyButton.text = jobUrlArray[indexPath.row]



//        let imageUrl = NSURL(string: imageUrlArray[indexPath.row])

//        if imageUrl != nil {
//            let data = NSData(contentsOf: (imageUrl as? URL)!)
//            cell.imageView?.image = UIImage (data: data as! Data)
//        }

        return cell

    }

}
```

Comment: in addition to the answers you already have - `JobUrl` should be the name of a class or a struct `jobUrl` is a variable name

Comment: Your code has the line `let url = NSURL(string: urlString)` that creates a URL from a String. Note that you should use `URL`, not `NSURL`, in Swift.

Answer (score 7):

You can't **cast** a string to a URL. Casting simply says "Ok, the thing in this box. It's not a string, it's an URL." If the object can't double as the other class, the cast fails.

You need to create a URL using a string as input:

```
let url = URL(string: myString)
```

Answer (score 0):

`String` and `URL` are not related therefore cannot be casted to each other. You have to create the URL from a string (like in another line in the code).

```
let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: URL(string: JobUrl)!)
```

Don't use `NSURL` in Swift 3 at all.

PS: Be aware that all optional bindings in `downloadJsonWithURL` are meaningless if you are using multiple arrays as data source. If one value does not pass the binding the app will crash at the latest in `cellForRow` due to an out-of-range exception.

Answer (score 0):

URL is an object which has different properties (like absoluteString,path, scheme etc. which are String objects themselves) so you cannot cast URL to String, they are different types.

With an URL you can use the URLSession class to access the contents of remote resource or represent a local path for example. Check the documentation and be sure that you know the classes you're using.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurl

In Swift try to create a URL with String (through unwrapping):

```
if let url = URL(String: jobUrlArray[indexPath.row]) { 
     let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: jobUrl)
}
```

or use `url?` in code

but be sure you don't use explicitly unwrapped optional like:

```
let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: URL(string: JobUrl)!)
```

your code might crash, it's not safe.